# Creating an IIS 6 Virtual Directory with PowerShell v2 over WMI/ADSI

Tags: iis, powershell, wmi, adsi

I can create an IISWebVirtualDir or IISWebVirtualDirSetting with WMI, but I've found no way to turn the virtual directory into an IIS Application. The virtual directory wants an AppFriendlyName and a Path. That's easy because they're part of the ...Setting object. But in order to turn the virtual directory into an App, you need to set AppIsolated=2 and AppRoot=[its root].

I cannot do this with WMI. I'd rather not mix ADSI and WMI, so if anyone can coach me through to amking this happen in WMI I'd be very happy.

Here's my demo code:

```
$server = 'serverName'
$site = 'W3SVC/10/ROOT/'
$app = 'AppName'
# If I use these args, the VirDir is not created at all. Fails to write read-only prop
# $args = @{'Name'=('W3SVC/10/ROOT/' + $app); `
#    'AppIsolated'=2;'AppRoot'='/LM/' + $site + $app}
# So I use this single arg
$args = @{'Name'=($site + $app)}
$args # Look at the args to make sure I'm putting what I think I am
$v = set-wmiinstance -Class IIsWebVirtualDir -Authentication PacketPrivacy `
    -ComputerName $server -Namespace root\microsoftiisv2 -Arguments $args
$v.Put()
# VirDir now exists

# Pull the settings object for it and prove I can tweak it
$filter = "Name = '" + $site + $app + "'"
$filter
$v = get-wmiobject -Class IIsWebVirtualDirSetting -Authentication PacketPrivacy `
    -ComputerName $server -Namespace root\microsoftiisv2 -Filter $filter
$v.AppFriendlyName = $app
$v.Put()
$v
# Yep. Changes work. Goes without saying I cannot change AppIsolated or AppRoot

# But ADSI can change them without a hitch
# Slower than molasses in January, but it works
$a = [adsi]("IIS://$server/" + $site + $app)
$a.Put("AppIsolated", 2)
$a.Put("AppRoot", ('/LM/' + $site + $app))
$a.Put("Path", "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\news")
$a.SetInfo()
$a
```

Any thoughts?

Update with working code

```
 $server = 'serverName'
$site = 'W3SVC/11/ROOT/'
$app = 'AppName'
$path = "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\news"

$args = @{'Name'=($site + $app)}
$v = set-wmiinstance -Class IIsWebVirtualDir -Authentication PacketPrivacy 
  -ComputerName $server -Namespace root\microsoftiisv2 -Arguments $args
$v.AppCreate2(2)


$filter = "Name = '" + $site + $app + "'"
$v = get-wmiobject -Class IIsWebVirtualDirSetting -Authentication PacketPrivacy 
 -ComputerName $server -Namespace root\microsoftiisv2 -Filter $filter
$v.AppFriendlyName = $app
$v.Path = $path
$v.Put()
```

Thanks Garrett and Glenn.

Comment: One other WMI whine. WMI provides no property on properties to easily identify whether that property is inherited. ADSI makes that a simple boolean. I'd sure love to do this in pure WMI, but they don't make it easy.

Comment: Ha! Little did I know. Sigh. When you create an object using WMI, inheritance is just blown away. WMI brings in every inherited property and hard-writes them into the new object. The metabase swells like the purple girl in Willie Wonka. The ADSI property IsInherit, though, ain't a cakewalk to find. I may end up having to walk parent/child to keep from creating props better inherited. Charming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested, but how about something along these lines:

```
$appCreateParams = $v.PSBase.GetMethodParameters("AppCreate2")
$appCreateParams["AppMode"] = 2

$v.PSBase.InvokeMethod("AppCreate2", $appCreateParams, null)
```

Comment: Garett, your code didn't work at all, but you convinced me to look for the AppCreate2 method in the WMI doc, and there it was. It'd been staring at me all along. The actual answer was as simple as $v.AppCreate2(2), and curse my eyes for failing me again. :-) Thanks!

Comment: InvokeMethod should work, but the syntax may be a little off. regardless, I'm glad to hear that you were able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing the AppCreate2 command? 
http://arcware.net/creating-iis-applications-with-powershell/

Comment: Glenn, the link you provided showed the AppCreate2 method being called on an ADSI object. That threw me off the scent (being easily distracted and all. :-) ) WMI does provide the same method, though, and it does work smoothly.